# Why mbed generating bin file different size online compiler and off line compile (export gcc_arm makefile)

Tags: arm, embedded, stm32, mbed

When build project on online ide genereted bin file size 21k but exported project that export settings Make-GCC-ARM, build with make command on linux terminal generated file size 52k.And how can reduce offline generated bin file size?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Online Mbed Compiler uses `ARMC6` toolchain to compile the code. While you are using `GCC_ARM` to compile locally. Different toolchains compile code differently hence the binary size difference.

If you use `ARMC6` toolchain locally to compile, the binary size will be very close to the one generated by an online compiler.

Comment: Yes the sub version makes the difference as well. But the major difference (like more than 2x the original size) in binary size is due to the different toolchain,

Comment: @hmxmghl. Thanks for answering. Are you sure online compiler uses ARMC6 because avaible options in export toolchain are make-armc5, vscode-armc5, eclipse-armc5..... but there is not armc6

Comment: Yes. It uses latest version of ARMCC toolchain. Reference: https://os.mbed.com/handbook/mbed-Compiler

Comment: @old_timer thank you. I made the edit to the answer as per your suggestion.